# How to get archive.org audio cover image through audio detail link using api?

Tags: java, android

Is there any way to get the cover art image link from the audio detail link or audio link?

**For example:**
https://archive.org/details/little_princess_krs

How can I get the cover art from this link using Archive.org API or any method?

Comment: did you able to solve it or you still need help on this one?

Comment: Solved, Thankyou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Archive.org provides data in json format simply if we add `?output=json` in the link.

For example , if I wanted to see json format details of https://archive.org/details/pilpay_2106_librivox then I will simply add `?outputjson`  in the last ie; https://archive.org/details/pilpay_2106_librivox?output=json